# Video recording does not save and hangs after adding [session addInput: audioInput] (audioInput = my audio device))

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I was able to save the file after recording without audio but after adding `[session addInput:audioInput]` to include audio on my video recording it gives me a console error

```
_playbackInterruptionDidEndNotification :: NSConcreteNotification 0x3ade70 {name = AVController_PlaybackInterruptionDidEndNotification; object = <AVController: 0x389130>; userInfo = {
"AVController_InterruptionStatusNotificationParameter" = "non-resumable.PlayAndRecord";
"AVController_InterruptorNameNotificationParameter" = RecorderServer;}}
, _state = 0
```

Here is the error on `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` function

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)" UserInfo=0x344be0 {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false}
```

Sometimes it records successfully and sometimes just stop recording and hangs. Its really hard to trace. Hope you can help me on this.

Thanks!